# Adding custom buttons to send message notification using Microsoft Band SDK

Tags: microsoft-band

I have been playing with the Microsoft Band SDK and I have figured out that it is possible to create custom tile layouts and buttons along with event click receivers like ACTION_TILE_OPENED, ACTION_TILE_BUTTON_PRESSED, and ACTION_TILE_CLOSED.

However, is it possible to add custom buttons when doing send message notifications? Such that when a message is receive, the user can swipe left and see additional action buttons he/she can tap, and also tie this button to a click handler method? I have been trying to figure this out all day, but no success.

Example: 
When a text (SMS) message is receive in the band, you can swipe left to see two buttons: "Dismiss" and "Reply". I was wondering if it is possible to also create this type of notification with buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, currently there are no means to customize notifications (messages or dialogs) sent to the Band.

Comment: Cool, at least that clears that out. Thanks for the info.